# latex reledmac/reledpar table and lineation / linecounter

Tags: parallel-processing, latex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{tibetan}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=harvardkyoto]{Sanskrit 2003}
\newfontfamily\tibetanfont{TibetanMachineUni.ttf}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=SimHei]{SimSun}
\usepackage{ctib}
\font\tibfont="Tibetan Machine Uni" at 11 pt
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage[nomaxlines]{reledpar}
% this are counter-macros for the parallel stuff
\newcounter{paral}
\setcounter{paral}{0}
\newcounter{parar}
\setcounter{parar}{0}
\newcommand{\sect}[1]{\pstart\centering{{\Large #1}} \\\pend}
\newcommand{\pdl}[2]{\expandafter\def\csname pul#1\endcsname{\addtocounter{paral}{1}\pstart\arabic{paral} #2 \\ \pend}}
\newcommand{\pdr}[2]{\expandafter\def\csname pur#1\endcsname{\addtocounter{parar}{1}\pstart\arabic{parar} #2 \\ \pend}}
% "d" for "define", "u" for "use".
\pdr{b}{\begin{tabular}{ p{7cm} p{7cm} }  \textbf{Skt: }\foreignlanguage{hindi}{tatra bhagavAn AyuSmantam AnandaM Amantrayate AgamayAnanda yena vaizAlI}\\ \textbf{Tib:} {\large \foreignlanguage{tibetan}{དེ་ནས་བཅོམ་ལྡན་འདས་ཀྱིས་ཚེ་དང་ལྡན་པ་ཀུན་དགའ་བོ་གྲོང་ཁྱེར་ཡངས་པ་ཅན་གང་ན་བར་འདོང་ངོ་ཞེས་བཀའ་སྩལ་པ་དང་།}} &  \textbf{T06:} 佛請賢者阿難，\\ \textbf{T05:} 佛從竹芳聚\footnote{Hier fehlt warscheinlich ein 出， siehe Parallel TODO: Parallel einfuegen} ，呼阿難：「且復還至維耶梨國。」 \\ \end{tabular}} 
\pdl{b}{\begin{tabular}{ p{7cm} p{7cm} }  \textbf{DN 16:} \emph{}& \textbf{D\={A}2:} \\ \textbf{T07:} 如是我聞：　一時，佛在毘耶離大林中重閣講堂，與大比丘眾千二百五十人俱。\\ \end{tabular}}

\pdr{c}{\begin{tabular}{ p{7cm} p{7cm} }  \textbf{Skt: }\foreignlanguage{hindi}{evaM bhadantety AyuSmAn Anando bhagavataH pratyazrauSIt atha bhagavAn vRjiSu janapadeSu caryAM caran vaizAlyAM viharati markkaTahradatIre kUTAgArazAlAyAM}\\ \textbf{Tib:} {\large \foreignlanguage{tibetan}{བཙུན་པ་དེ་བཞིན་བགྱིའོ་ཞེས་ཆེ་དང་ལྡན་པ་ཀུན་དགའ་བོས་བཅོམ་ལྡན་འདས་ལས་མཉན་ཏེ། དེ་ནས་བཅོམ་ལྡན་འདས་ཡུལ་བྲྀ་ཛི་ནས་ལྗོངས་རྒྱུ་ཞིང་གྲོང་ཁྱེར་ཡངས་པ་ཅན་དུ་བྱོན་ཏེ་ཡངས་པ་ཅན་གྱི་སྤྲེའུ་རྫིང་གི་འགྲམ་ཁང་བཟངས་བརྩེགས་པའི་གནས་ན་བཞུགས་སོ། །}} &  \textbf{T06:} 受教即行。既到止猿猴館，\\ \textbf{T05:} 阿難言：「受教。」佛還維耶梨國， \\ \end{tabular}}
\pdl{c}{\begin{tabular}{ p{7cm} p{7cm} }  \textbf{DN 16:} \emph{atha kho bhagav\={a} pubba\d nhasamaya\d m niv\={a}setv\={a} pattac\={\i}varam \={a}d\={a}ya ves\={a}li\d m pi\d n\d d\={a}ya p\={a}visi}& \textbf{D\={A}2:} \\ \textbf{T07:} 爾時，世尊而與阿難，於晨朝時，著衣持缽，入城乞食，\\ \end{tabular}}
\pdr{d}{\begin{tabular}{ p{7cm} p{7cm} }  \textbf{Skt: }\foreignlanguage{hindi}{atha bhagavAn pUrvAhNe niyasya pAtracIvaraM AdAya vaizAlIM piNDAya prAvizad AyuSmatAnandena pazcAt zramaNena}\\ \textbf{Tib:} {\large \foreignlanguage{tibetan}{དེ་ནས་བཅོམ་ལྡན་འདས་སྔ་དྲོ་ཤམ་ཐབས་དང་། ཆོས་གོས་མན་བས་ལྷུང་བཟེད་བསྣམས་ཏེ། ཡངས་པ་ཅན་དུ་ཞབས་འབྲིང་བའི་དགེ་སྦྱོང་ཀུན་དགའ་བོ་དང་བསོད་སྙོམས་ལ་ཞུགས་སོ། །}} &  \textbf{T06:} 行乞食畢，滌缽澡洗，\\ \textbf{T05:} 入城持缽行分衛， \\ \end{tabular}}
\pdl{d}{\begin{tabular}{ p{7cm} p{7cm} }  \textbf{DN 16:} \emph{ves\={a}liya\d m pi\d n\d d\={a}ya caritv\={a} pacch\={a}bhatta\d m pi\d n\d dap\={a}tapa\d tikkhanto}& \textbf{D\={A}2:} \\ \textbf{T07:} 還歸所止，食竟洗漱，收攝衣缽，\\ \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages} \begin{Leftside}\beginnumbering \pulb \pulc \puld \endnumbering\end{Leftside} \begin{Rightside}\beginnumbering \purb \purc \purd \endnumbering\end{Rightside} \end{pages} \Pages
\end{document}
```

The aim is to have four columns of text facing over two pages with synched paragraphs. 
So far I get the behavior that I want, but the paragraphs on the two pages are out of sync. The tables themselves look nice though. So I assume that the tables somehow block the linecounter from working in the correct way, as the lineation on both sides is also not increased in the way it should be.
Here you can see the problem: 
[image: Here you can see how the problem looks]